# How do I do boolean criteria filtering within a column when using grouping by in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I like to work with data.table and preferably in long-formatted data. I am referring to the kind of data one has after a `melt` rather then wide data as one has after a `dcast`

In our laboratory we have many specimens each with its own nucleic.acid.nr. Over the years we have determined which types of HPV are in each specimen by one of various techniques (reflected in column called "source"). Here is a excerpt of the data.

```
hpv.type <- structure(list(nucleic.acid.nr = c(1649, 1649, 1649, 1651, 1651, 
1651, 1651, 1654, 1654, 1654, 1654, 1657, 1657, 1661, 1661, 1661, 
1661, 1665, 1665, 1672, 1675, 1675, 1677, 1677, 1677, 1680, 1680, 
1682, 1682, 1682, 1683, 1683, 1683, 1687, 1687, 1689, 1689, 1689, 
1696, 1696, 1696, 1697, 1697, 1697, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1703, 1703, 
1703, 1709, 1709, 1710, 1710, 1710, 1713, 1713, 1713, 1716, 1716, 
1721, 1721, 1724, 1724, 1726, 1726, 1729, 1729, 1732, 1732, 1732, 
1735, 1735, 1735, 1740, 1740, 1748, 1748, 1748, 1750, 1750), 
    hpvtype = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("6", 
    "11", "6, 11", "16", "18", "6, 16", "11, 16", "11, 67", "6, 11, 16", 
    "6, 11, 31", "6, 11, 59", "6, 11, 76", "6, 16, 18", "6, 28", 
    "6, 72a"), class = "factor"), source = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
    5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
    1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
    3L, 5L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("typeseq", "linear array", "sequence clust", 
    "aspcr rflp", "nci", "provided to us"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-81L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), sorted = c("nucleic.acid.nr", 
"source"))
```

I want to know which samples have undergone typing by BOTH linear array and TypeSeq. I called the data.table hpv.type

I thought this would work.

```
library(data.table)
hpv.type[ , .SD[,.(both.of.two.methods=all(source=="linear array", source=="typeseq"))], by=nucleic.acid.nr]
```

Every sample is said to be FALSE but that is not correct. Several of the nucleic.acid.nr were subjected to linear array AND TypeSeq. What am I not understanding about boolean criteria within one column within an .SD?

By the way, this works as expected if I want to find the samples that were subjected either to linear array OR TypeSeq.

```
hpv.type[ , .SD[,.(either.of.two.methods=any(source=="linear array", source=="typeseq"))], by=nucleic.acid.nr]
```

Quite surprising to me was the fact that I did not even need to invoke the whole .SD thing. I get the same results if I do not use .SD.

Next question will be to analyse the difference in HPV type results as a function of how we sourced the information (ie by what method). So I will once again be wanting to do some comparrisons of different rows in the same column by sample. But lets keep it simple for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms if you dataset it seems you want to know for each `nucleic.acid.nr` if source contains both `linear array` and `typeseq`? Here is one relatively simple option:

```
hpv.type[, all(c("linear array", "typeseq") %in% source), by = nucleic.acid.nr
         ][(V1), nucleic.acid.nr]
# [1] 1651 1654 1657 1661 1696
```

Comment: Why is the `V1` in parentheses?

Comment: Good question. If you remove the parentheses and try to run the query again you'll get a error messaging explaining why that won't work and other options.

Answer (score 1):

I think logically you mean this:

```
hpv.type[, .SD[, .(both.of.two.methods=all(
  any(source=="linear array"), 
  any(source=="typeseq")
  ))], by=nucleic.acid.nr]
```

or more simply

```
hpv.type[, .(
  both.of.two.methods = any(source=="linear array") & any(source=="typeseq")
), by=nucleic.acid.nr]
```